# Usage for lru cache in functools

Tags: python, lru, functools

I want to use lru_cache in my code, however, I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'lru_cache' is not defined
```

I do have an import functools in my code but that does not help

Example code is here:

```
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you really just wrote `import functools`, then that's not enough. You need to either import the `lru_cache` symbol with `from functools import lru_cache`, or you need to qualify the name when you attempt to use it, like `@functools.lru_cache`.

There's nothing special about the functools module in this respect. *All* modules work this way. You've probably noticed when you've imported other modules and used other functions.

Answer (score 7):

You need to import `lru_cache` before using it:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Or alternatively refer to it with full name when importing `functools`:

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fib(n):
```

Comment: can we use @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=32) for multiple functions in the same file?

Answer (score 2):

The import line is not included in the question, but it should be:

```
from functools import lru_cache
```

Alternatively, the function decorator could be changed to:

```
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
```

Comment: can we use @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=32) for multiple function in same file?

Answer (score 2):

Another side point, [according to documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) is that:

> If maxsize is set to None, the LRU feature is disabled and the cache
>   can grow without bound. The LRU feature performs best when maxsize is
>   a power-of-two.

#### Documentation Example

```
import functools
import urllib
import requests

    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=32)
    def get_pep(num):
        'Retrieve text of a Python Enhancement Proposal'
        resource = 'http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-%04d/' % num
        try:
            with urllib.request.urlopen(resource) as s:
                return s.read()
        except urllib.error.HTTPError:
            return 'Not Found'


    for n in 8, 290, 308, 320, 8, 218, 320, 279, 289, 320, 9991:
        pep = get_pep(n)
        print(n, len(pep))

    print(get_pep.cache_info())
```

#### Output

```
8 106439
290 59766
308 56972
320 49551
8 106439
218 46795
320 49551
279 48553
289 50882
320 49551
9991 9
CacheInfo(hits=3, misses=8, maxsize=32, currsize=8)
```

Comment: can we use ```@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=32)``` for multiple function in same file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use LRU cache for asynchronous function it won't work. Try [async-cache](https://pypi.org/project/async-cache/) . It supports async type functions in python also you can use user defined datatypes along with primitive datatypes as params in cached function. This is not supported in functools.lru_cache